# Deleting a collection when closing a CollectionView in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: marionette

After closing a CollectionView in my project, the collection it makes reference to is still available. Opening again the CollectionView duplicates the collection as it reloads the data again. I think this is expected behaviour as in the [documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionview-close) it says that all the CollectionView does on close is:

1. unbind all listenTo events
2. unbind all custom view events
3. unbind all DOM events
4. unbind all item views that were rendered
5. remove this.el from the DOM
6. call an onClose event on the view, if one is provided

I'm guessing it's on me to manage the collection on the onClose event handler. Is there a good way of deleting the collection and models associated with the view?

Answer (score 2):

In your situation it's not necessary to delete the collection. Variables (in this case your collection) that are not directly referenced by another object will be garbage collected by javascript. So when the view and module close and nothing else is referencing the collection it will be removed.

If you want to make absolutely sure you won't get any zombie events you can clear it's event listeners when you close the module and/or view:

```
myCollection.off();
```

Of course is your collection is a global variable (technically a property of the window object) then yes it might be a good idea to delete it like so:

```
delete window.myCollection;
```

Aside from this, removing it from memory is not something you need to worry about as the other objects referencing are closed...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I didn't explain myself very well. The view is associated with a submodule that I load and unload on demand, but I cannot assume that the data will be needed again. So when I unload the module and I delete the view I want to also delete the collection and models associated with it. To remove the module and view I just replace the region it is using with another module, the view closes correctly but the collection stays in memory.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you now--I'll update my answer but before I do just so I understand for sure: is anything else besides the module and the view referencing the collection which you wish to delete?

Comment: Thanks! I think both, the module and the view, are being deleted ok so the only remaining thing to remove from memory is the collection and its models.

Comment: Answer updated. The short answer is don't worry about it they will go away on their own :)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying it out and I thought it actually worked. I was using just a plain delete on my onClose method, but the collection and the models are still appearing on DevTools' heap snapshot so I guess they are not gone. I'll look into it because it's probably something I'm doing wrong.